# playing array of sound

Tags: android, audio

I want to play audio in an array, when I click on a button an image gets loaded and sound gets played. If i again click on that button the next image gets loaded and so the next sound. I am able to change the images but unable to change the sound as per the combination. Please help. Below is the source code.

```
sounds = new int [] {
            R.raw.marathi_one, R.raw.marathi_two, R.raw.marathi_three, R.raw.marathi_four
    };
    mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[0]);

next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
mediaplayer.start();
            sound++;
            sound = sound % sounds.length;
            }
});
```

I just want to increment the value of array so that all the sound present in the array gets played.

Answer (score 0):

Must be `sound=0;`

```
    sounds = new int [] {
                R.raw.marathi_one, R.raw.marathi_two, R.raw.marathi_three, R.raw.marathi_four
        };


    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[sound]);
              mediaplayer.start();
               sound++;
                }

});
```

Comment: playing the same sound i.e. first sound

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
nextTrack(i);
i++
}
```

where `i` is an index starting from 0 and incremented in `OnClick` method

```
void nextTrack(int i)
{
 sounds = new int [] {
            R.raw.marathi_one, R.raw.marathi_two, R.raw.marathi_three, R.raw.marathi_four
    };
    mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[i]);
   mediaplayer.start();
}
```